# How do I configure Hadoop such that one specific node stores all the data on HDFS?

Tags: hadoop

We have a very stable machine which we would like to use it as Namenode. Meanwhile, we have a lot of other machines which are highly unstable and we want them to be Datanodes. Now we want to configure Hadoop in a way that the Namenode (also as a Datanode in this case) has a copy of the entire data on HDFS such that the cluster can always recover data from it. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in a straightforward manner. There is a way, but it is messy and fraught with all kinds of problems, and will not be worth it.

Run the datanode daemons on your actual datanodes and also on the namenode. In your topology file, make all the real datanodes as part of one logical rack(R1), and the NN+DN machine as a different rack (R2). Make sure that your NN+DN has more space than 2*(total disk capacity of all DNs). Ensure that HDFS is configured with replication factor of 3.

When a block is created, HDFS will put 2 replicas on one rack, and a third replica on another rack. So all your data will be on the NN+DN single host for sure. What this will do to your cluster's performance is something that I do not want to get into.

Do not even think of doing this in a production environment. In fact, your requirement is completely flawed. Having multiple replicas across datanodes is how Hadoop addresses Datanode reliability. The assumption is that datanodes will keep failing and yet data should not be lost - this is baked into the Hadoop design.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not inherently not scalable - system  will be limited by data volume of only one node. 
I have faced similar requirements and the solution was to build smaller HDFS cluster with a lot of storage and little CPU and memory (to save money).  Then we can DISTCP data periodically to this cluster as a backup.